# Rails combining pdfs from action stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation

I have an action in my controller `#applications` that renders a html page of my websites application page. When I specify the path for this action with the :pdf format it will render the page as a pdf (which works correctly).

I am writing another action `#applications_print_version` that needs to contain the rendered view from `#applications` plus some other pdfs (from a list of urls). Using combine_pdf I have been able to get the list of pdfs via urls working, but I can not get the `#applications` view to be added to the combined pdf in the `#applications_print_version` working.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def applications_print_version
    html = render_to_string(action: :applications) 
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html) 

    new_pdf = CombinePDF.new
    new_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf)

    #List of pdfs I got from somewhere else
    @pdf_attachments.each { |att| new_pdf << CombinePDF.parse( Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( att.url ) ) ) }

    send_data new_pdf.to_pdf, :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf"
end
```

This solution does have all the data, but the `pdf` variable has no styling. I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Are there any error codes or warnings in the log?

Comment: @Myst, no. There is just a log of rendered partials.

Comment: try saving interim results for testing (i.e. add an `IO.binwrite 'step1.pdf', pdf`)... what does the Wicked PDF look like?

Comment: I just had a funny thought... if your CSS is in a separate file, make sure the URL for the CSS file is absolute rather then relative - otherwise it might not be available when using the `applications_print_version` URL.

Comment: Any updates? did you find a solution?

Comment: @Myst I haven't had a chance to try yet. Hopefully tonight or tomorrow. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: @Myst I tried the IO.binwrite 'step.pdf', pdf but I couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure I used it correctly.

Comment: @Myst regarding using absolute paths. I believe that's what this issue is referring to, but following the suggestions did not work for my application. [link](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a local community support I have managed to get it to work. There were a few things I needed to fix.

The layout that I was using to render `#applications` was using my standard pdf layout that I used for PDFKit. I duplicated the layout and replaced

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

with

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
```

One I did that I could render the `#applications` action with the layout the WickedPDF needed.

```
html = render_to_string(action: :applications, layout: 'wicked_pdf')
```

I ran into another issue. There is a known issue with WickedPDF https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470

So I had to remove any instances of `@import "bootstrap"` in my stylesheets which is not ideal, but I could not resolve the above issue.

Any now the `#applications_print_version` works correctly!

If anyone can do better, please let me know, I would like to know :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that the **pdf_from_string** method expects a **String** class to be passed, but the **render_to_string** method is not returning a string class.

Try obtaining the HTML content using File.read or another approach.